# Legend title pad in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I would like the title in the legend of my matplotlib figure to be more distant from the content of the legend. Currently, I have the following:[image: Current legend, with title too close to content]

I see the [`set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend.set_title) function of the `Legend` class accepts a `prop` dictionary, which should be the one described in the [text properties page](https://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html). This one contains the field `bbox`, where a `pad` property could be added. But when I try something like the following

```
legend.set_title('Legend', prop={'bbox':{'pad':somepad}})
```

python complains that `bbox` is not an accepted parameter.

I'm using matplotlib 2.1.0 under Python 3.6.3 on Arch Linux.

---

An obvious workaround would be add a linebreak, like this:

```
legend.set_title('Legend\n ')
```

Although one might like the result, matplotlib has the great advantage that everything can be configured to the slightest detail, so I'm looking for a solution which gives me more fine-grained control over this spacing.

Comment: `prop`is for `FontProperties`, not `Text` properties.

Answer (score 7):

Of course introducing a linebreak in the title text as `legend.set_title('Legend\n ')` is a valid option.

If you don't like that you can set the separation between title and legend handle box manually as

```
legend._legend_box.sep = 20
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2], label="some")
plt.plot([1,3], label="label")

legend = plt.legend(title="Legend title", ncol=2)
legend._legend_box.sep = 20

plt.show()
```

[image]

The default separation is `labelspacing * fontsize`, hence

```
plt.rcParams["legend.labelspacing"] * plt.rcParams["font.size"] == 0.5 * 10 == 5
```